# SoundCloud - 401 HTTP Status Code

Tags: ios, soundcloud, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to access public resources from SoundCloud. The URL's I've been sending have been working great for the past few weeks. I uploaded my build to TestFlight and (not sure if at all related, but...) now I'm getting 401 status code from the response, so there's no JSON to parse.

The URL I'm sending from my client (iOS) works fine in Chrome, so my client ID is clearly up-to-date. It's just not working from the client. And I haven't directly changed any related code that may have tampered with the request since it last worked.

What gives here?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, I can only make a guess at what could be wrong.

Do you have different configurations for Debug and Release builds?  Are you using a different API key?  It is possible that due to a misconfiguration your `CLIENT_ID` is not being sent with your request under the Release configuration, causing the 401 error.

Additionally, if you're using separate plist files for each configuration, make sure your `NSAppTransportSecurity` keys are set properly: either using `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` or whitelisting Soundcloud with `NSExceptionDomains`.

Comment: I'm sending the same url almost everytime with the same client ID: "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?q=\(searchTerm)&limit=20&format=json?client_id=xxxxxxxxxx". Haven't updated the client Id from debug to release

Comment: Also, I'm getting JSON from YouTube with the same code/method, only difference being the url, and that's working fine.

Comment: Are you using OAuth at all?  Or just a Client ID for your API calls?

Comment: Just a client id. I'm only accessing public resources